# When trying to use bitset <N>::reference, the compiler throws an error

Tags: c++, templates

Why is this code causing a compiler error??

```or-tag-here
template <size_t N>
class A
{
    bitset<N> _bits;
    void foo(bitset<N>::reference* ref) // this does not compile
    {
        //some code
    }
};
```

Is N != сonstexpr in this situation??

Error: C2061
syntax error: indentifier 'reference'

Comment: please include the error message

Comment: It needs to be `typename bitset<N>::reference*`

Comment: @Artyer: It really helped. Could You tell exactly how this helped and why?

Comment: @doctal Because if you have `template<std::size_t N> struct bitset { using reference = ...; }`, you could theoretically have a specialisation `template<> struct bitset<5> { static int reference; }` where `reference` isn't the name of the type. In this ambiguous case with a dependent name, the compiler always assumes that the name is a value rather than a type, and of course a value doesn't make sense there. The `typename` forces it to be parsed as a type instead.